# Verificar usuario Unix

Tags: golang

Para verificar o nome do usuário consigo facilmente utilizar:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

fmt.Println(os.Getenv("USER"))
```

Porém para facilitar um pouco as coisas eu gostaria de adicionar uma nova função ao `struct os`, então fiz da seguinte maneira:

```
func (system os) Sudo() bool {
    return system.Getenv("USER") == "root"
}

func main() {
    if !os.Sudo() {
        fmt.Println("You have no permission to run as non-root user. Use sudo")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

O erro que recebo é:

> use of package os without selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde eu saiba, talvez esteja errado, não há como estender funções ou interfaces no Golang, criados por outros packages, muito menos neste caso.

Primeiro, é preciso que defina nos `imports` o `os`, mas isso não será resolver o problema.

---

```
func (system os) Sudo() bool {
    return system.Getenv("USER") == "root"
}
```

Você na verdade espera que o `os` seja um struct/interface, o que de fato ele não é. O `os` é um package.

---

No seu caso o que pode fazer é criar uma nova pasta, por exemplo "systemOS" e então nele declarar "package systemOS", por exemplo:

```
package systemOS

import "os"

func Sudo() bool {
    return system.Getenv("USER") == "root"
}
```

Agora você poderia chamar na sua main, desde que dê o import no `systemOS` recem criado:

```
func main() {
    if !systemOS.Sudo() {
        fmt.Println("You have no permission to run as non-root user. Use sudo")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

---

Em outros casos, você pode criar um "sinônimo" (um alias) para um outro tipo. Para o exemplo ficar mais fácil irei usar o `os/user` que nele contêm um struct de [`user.User`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/user/#User).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/user"
)

type X user.User

func (u X) IsInkeliz() bool {
    return u.Name == "Inkeliz"
}

func main() {
    acc, err := user.Current()
    if err != nil {
        panic("")
    }

    if !X(*acc).IsInkeliz() {
        fmt.Println("Você não é Inkeliz")
    }
}
```

O `X` é um tipo que é o mesmo que `user.User`. Então eu converto `X(*acc)` e consigo acessar o `IsInkeliz()` que criei, dentro da função também consigo acessar o `.Name` que é da struct original (do user.User).

Uma outra forma de fazer seria também criar um Struct:

```
type X struct {
    y *user.User
}
```

Então colocar o `acc` dentro dele e poderia acessar o `y.Name`.

Porém, em todos os casos você estará criando um novo tipo. Desconheço alguma forma de "estender" o tipo estabelecido por outro package sem ter que criar um novo tipo.